# Как определить процент заряда батареи андроид

Tags: java, android, xml, android-textview

Нужен пример кода, где происходит получение заряда батареи и выведение его на TextView

Comment: в офц. документации все есть https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html

Answer (score 3):

Согласно `en-SO` надо [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15746919/3212712):

```
public float getBatteryLevel() {
    Intent batteryIntent = registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
    int level = batteryIntent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
    int scale = batteryIntent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);

    // Error checking that probably isn't needed but I added just in case.
    if(level == -1 || scale == -1) {
        return 50.0f;
    }

    return ((float)level / (float)scale) * 100.0f; 
}
```

Comment: ЮрийСПб, а как вивести значение в textview?

Comment: @Вадим, `textView.setText(text);`